# Left Align Row 2 in all Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to align all the second rows in my spreadsheet. The code I wrote is not looping through all the sheets and only applying the left align to the first sheet.

```
Sub leftAlign()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    Rows(2).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the `ws` variable in your loop (otherwise only the active sheet will have the code applied) and you don't need to Select. Also, for one line the With is overkill I'd say.

```
Sub leftAlign()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws.Rows(2)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
 Next ws
End Sub
```